# How to implement radio button in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am converting React code to React Native. So I need to implement radio buttons.

Answer (score 128):

You can mimic a radio button really easily using just barebones RN. Here's one simple implementation which I use. Tweak size, colors etc. as you like. It looks like this (with a different tint, and some text). Add `TouchableOpacity` on top to turn it into a button that does something.

[image]

```
function RadioButton(props) {
  return (
      <View style={[{
        height: 24,
        width: 24,
        borderRadius: 12,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#000',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }, props.style]}>
        {
          props.selected ?
            <View style={{
              height: 12,
              width: 12,
              borderRadius: 6,
              backgroundColor: '#000',
            }}/>
            : null
        }
      </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Excellent approach.  Married with the proper state variables, this can either be checkboxes or radio buttons.

Comment: Looks great but the main purpose of a radio button aside from its visual aspect is it's functionality. This shouldn't be an answer.

Answer (score 21):

This is another way of creating radioButtons ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcFz9ey8GXM), thanks to php step by step channel)

***Method 1***

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        radioBtnsData: ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'],
        checked: 0
    }
}
```

---

```
import { View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

{this.state.radioBtnsData.map((data, key) => {
    return (
        <View key={key}>
            {this.state.checked == key ?
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                    <Image style={styles.img} source={require("./img/rb_selected.png")}/>
                    <Text>{data}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                :
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.setState({checked: key})}} style={styles.btn}>
                    <Image style={styles.img} source={require("./img/rb_unselected.png")} />
                    <Text>{data}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        </View>
    )
})}
```

---

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    img:{
        height:20,
        width: 20
    },
    btn:{
        flexDirection: 'row'
    }
});
```

Place below images in img folder

[image] [image]

***Method 2***

**Elaborated LaneRettig ex for new developers**

Thanks to Lane Rettig

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      radioSelected: 1
    }
  }


  radioClick(id) {
    this.setState({
      radioSelected: id
    })
  }

  render() {

    const products = [{
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3
    }];

    return (
      products.map((val) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity key={val.id} onPress={this.radioClick.bind(this, val.id)}>
            <View style={{
              height: 24,
              width: 24,
              borderRadius: 12,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: '#000',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
              {
                val.id == this.state.radioSelected ?
                  <View style={{
                    height: 12,
                    width: 12,
                    borderRadius: 6,
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                  }} />
                  : null
              }
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: It through an error too many re-renders

Answer (score 7):

There is a react-native component called [react-native-radio-buttons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-radio-buttons) that may do some of what you need:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution for radio button using functional components.

> **Note** - I have used images for checked & unchecked radio icon

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';

const Radio = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(0);
  var gender = ['Male', 'Female'];
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.btn}>
        {gender.map((gender, key) => {
          return (
            <View key={gender}>
              {checked == key ? (
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.img}
                    source={require('../images/radio_Checked.jpg')}
                  />
                  <Text>{gender}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    setChecked(key);
                  }}
                  style={styles.btn}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.img}
                    source={require('../images/radio_Unchecked.png')}
                  />
                  <Text>{gender}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
      {/* <Text>{gender[checked]}</Text> */}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  radio: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  img: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  btn: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default Radio;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `Checkbox` in `react-native` for creating the radio button. Please refer below code.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {radioButton:'value1'};
}
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <CheckBox 
                title='value1'
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                checked={this.state.radioButton === 'value1'}
                onPress={() => this.setState({radioButton: 'value1'})}
                ></CheckBox>
            <CheckBox 
                title='value2'
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                checked={this.state.radioButton === 'value2'}
                onPress={() => this.setState({radioButton: 'value2'})}
                ></CheckBox> 
            <CheckBox 
                title='value3'
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                checked={this.state.radioButton === 'value3'}
                onPress={() => this.setState({radioButton: 'value3'})}
                ></CheckBox> 
            <CheckBox 
                title='value4'
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                checked={this.state.radioButton === 'value4'}
                onPress={() => this.setState({radioButton: 'value4'})}
                ></CheckBox> 
            <CheckBox 
                title='value5'
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                checked={this.state.radioButton === 'value5'}
                onPress={() => this.setState({radioButton: 'value5'})}
                ></CheckBox>  

        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: -> https://reactnative.dev/docs/checkbox  is Removed in the last verions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could style into a circle button such as a radio button or something:
[image: example Tabs or same concept]

```
const period = [
      {
        key: 1,
        name : '1 Month',
        value : 1,

      },
      {
        key : 2,
        name : '12 Month',
        value : 12,

      }
    ];

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 0,
        };
      }

    onChangeTabs = (tabs) => {

        this.setState({
          value : tabs,

        })

      }

    renderTabs = () => {
        return period.map(item => (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            key={item.key}
            value={item.value}
            onPress={this.onChangeTabs.bind(this, item.value)}
          >
            <View style={this.state.value == item.value ? styles.periodActive : styles.period}>
              <Text style={styles.periodText}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        ));
      };


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    period: {
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 1,

        marginHorizontal: 5,
      },
      periodActive: {
        backgroundColor: '#333',
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function RadioButton() {
const [radioButton, setRadioButton] = useState("Yes");
return (
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRadioButton("Yes")}>
    <Text>
      <Ionicons name={ radioButton === "Yes" ? "radio-button-on" : "radio-button-off" } size={18} color="green" /> 
      Yes
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
    
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRadioButton("No")}>
    <Text>
      <Ionicons name={radioButton === "No" ? "radio-button-on" : "radio-button-off"} size={18} color="green" />
      No
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
)}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-radio-input.
Its very simple to use.

```
import RadioGroup,{Radio} from "react-native-radio-input";
.
.
.
//Receive the checked value (ES6 syntax)
getChecked = (value) => {
// value = our checked value
alert(value)
}
 <RadioGroup getChecked={this.getChecked}>
  <Radio iconName={"lens"} label={"The first option"} value={"A"} />
  <Radio iconName={"lens"} label={"The first option"} value={"B"} />
  <Radio iconName={"lens"} label={"I need numbers"} value={1} />
  <Radio label={"Is IconName Optional?"} value={"Yes"} />
  <Radio label={"Show Sentence Value"} value={"This is a Sentence"} />
</RadioGroup>
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import RadioForm, { RadioButton, RadioButtonInput, RadioButtonLabel } from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';
const radioProps = [
  { label: 'Male', value: false },
  { label: 'Female, value: true }
];



<View style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
                <RadioForm
                  buttonColor={gray}
                  buttonSize={12}
                  radioStyle={{paddingTop:25}}
                  selectedButtonColor="#000000"
                  radio_props={radioProps}
                  initial={0}
                  animation={false}
                  onPress={(value) => setGender(value)}
                />
              </View>
```

Comment: Working both in android as well ios fine

Answer (score 0):

i am using my own custom radio buttons group.it style can be custmoized also.

```
 // radio button component
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'

const RadioButtons = (props) => {
  const radioPress = () => {
props.setChecked(props?.item?.id)
  }
  return (
    <View style={{
  flexDirection: "row",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  margin:5,
}}>

  <TouchableOpacity style={{
  }} onPress={radioPress}>

    <View style={[{
      height: 24,
      width: 24,
      borderRadius: 12,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#000',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }, props.style]}>
      {
        props?.checked == props?.item?.id ?
          <View style={{
            height: 12,
            width: 12,
            borderRadius: 6,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
          }} />
          : null
      }
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <Text style={{
    marginLeft: 5,
    fontWeight:"500",
    fontSize:20,
    textTransform:"capitalize"

  }}>
    {props?.item?.label}
  </Text>

</View>
 )
}

export default RadioButtons
```

used in any where eg:

```
   <View style={{
                    flexDirection:"row",
                    flexWrap:"wrap",
                }}>
                    {
                        [{label:'male',id:0}, {label:'female',id:1}, 
   {label:'other',id:2}].map((item,i)=>{
                            return(
                                <RadioButtons key={i} item={item} checked= 
  {checked} setChecked={setChecked} />
                            ) 
                        })
                    }
                </View>
```