# How to add radio button in react native?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, react-native, radio-button, jsx

I want to add radio button in react native, which is pretty simple and I've done it. But the thing is I want to loop through the radio button upon the contents fetching from a server.So the list depends on the number of items fetching which is changing.The data I'm fetching is as follows

**json data**

```
{
    "data": [{
        "content": "question",
        "selection": [
            "(a).option1",
            "(b).option2 ",
            "(c).option3 ",
            "(d).option4 "
        ],
        "correct": "4",
    }]
}
```

Well, I'm displaying `content` inside a `CardSection` component.I want to loop through the `selection` array with corresponding radio buttons.I'm using map method for rendering the `data`. So for `selection` what should I use?A for loop is okay for that?But I don't know how to do it please do help.Following is the react part.

**updated**

```
    const formatArray = (arr) => {
  let newArr = []
  arr.map((item, index) => newArr.push({'label': index, value: item}))
  return newArr
}
class QASection extends Component{
render() {

    _setActive = (active) => this.setState({this.setState({selected:value})})

    return(
    {this.state.details.map(a =>
    <Card>
    <CardSection>
    <Text>{a.content}</Text>
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection>
        <RadioForm
          radio_props={radio_props}
          initial={0}
          itemShowKey="label"
          itemRealKey="value"
          dataSource={formatArray(data)}
          onPress={onPress}
        />
<CardSection data={data} key={index} onPress={this._setActive} />
    </Card>
    )}
    );
     } 
}
```

By rendering `selection[0]` it will give me the first value in `selection` array. But how do I loop through this with radio buttons for each item in an array?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889921/how-to-implement-radio-button-in-react-native

Comment: This is not the one i'm looking for. How to loop over the json data here?

Answer (score 0):

You can **loop** in the following way

I assume that you are using [`react-native-radio-form`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-radio-form)

```
const formatArray = (arr) => {
  let newArr = []
  arr.map((item, index) => newArr.push({'label': index, value: item}))
  return newArr
}

const YourCardComponent = ({data, onPress}) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardSection>
        <Text>{data.content}</Text>
      </CardSection>
      <CardSection>
        <RadioForm
          radio_props={radio_props}
          itemShowKey="label"
          itemRealKey="value"
          dataSource={formatArray(data.selection)}
          onPress={onPress}
          // ... other props as required
        />
      </CardSection>
    </Card>
  )
}

    // Inside the class


_setActive = (active) => this.setState({selected:value})

render () {
  const {details} = this.state
  return (
    <View>
      {details.map((data, index) => (
        <YourCardComponent data={data} key={index} onPress={this._setActive} />
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Actually i'm using class based component since i'm fetching data from server. So can i use separate `render` methods?

Comment: No, you can't, just use `_setActive` and `render` inside the class

Comment: you might need to format the `selection` array to set the `label` according to your needs, in the `formatArray` func

Comment: Okay so where do i fetch the `selection` array  within the render?I mean inside `CardSection`?I've updated my question based on your answer please do help.

Comment: Do i need to give like this `arr.map((item,index) => newArr.push({'label': index, value: a.selection}))`

Comment: Yes, check the updated code, rest depends upon your use case

Comment: Yeah i've changed but nothing is showing other than `content`.No radio buttons or options

Comment: How can i loop over the `selection` array here?

Comment: The `radioForm` expects an `array`, it should automatically loop and render

Comment: Yeah but values are getting as `undefined ` when i given `itemShowKey={a.selection}` and `itemRealKey={a.selection}`. What should i give instead?

Comment: It accepts `strings` not `objects`, ie `object keys as string`