# How would I create gender selected button when using react native?

Tags: react-native

I am creating an app and face the problem I want to create two button when one is active other is inactive

Comment: Where does 'gender' come into play?

Comment: I don't know how to do this

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried?

Comment: I have design < three buttons <male><female><other> when user select male the others are inactive

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement radio button in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889921/how-to-implement-radio-button-in-react-native)

Comment: I am Using React native segment control Button , It's working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use [switch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html) or else you can use change color of button to show active and inactive.

example of using state variable

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

class Test extends Component {
    state = {
        gender: 'male',
        maleButtonColor: '#841584',
        femaleButtonColor: '#C0C0C0'
    }


    onSubmitEmailRP() {
        this.password.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            gender: 'male',
                            maleButtonColor: '#841584',
                            femaleButtonColor: '#C0C0C0'
                        })
                    }}
                    title="Male"
                    color="#841584"
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            gender: 'female',
                            maleButtonColor: '#C0C0C0',
                            femaleButtonColor: '#841584'
                        })
                    }}
                    title="Female"
                    color="#841584"
                />
            </View>);
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: but How to control two button dependent on each other

Comment: Thanks , I am using react-native-segment-control button

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ButtonGroup`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html) of `react-native-elements` for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example according to your requirement.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import RadioGroup from 'react-native-radio-buttons-group';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        gender: [
            {
                label: 'Male',
                color: 'green',
            },
            {
                label: 'Female',
                color: 'green',
            }
        ],
    };

    onPress = gender => this.setState({ gender });

    render() {
        let selectedGender = this.state.gender.find(e => e.selected == true);
        selectedGender = selectedGender ? selectedGender.value : this.state.gender[0].label;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.header}>
                    Selected Gender - {selectedGender}
                </Text>
                <RadioGroup radioButtons={this.state.gender} onPress={this.onPress} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    header: {
        fontSize: 18, 
        marginBottom: 50,
    },
});
```

Comment: When I use RadioGroup my app is slow down It takes 1 to 1.5 mnt to move the next screen